# Skype mutes In-game sounds

Tags: windows-8, audio, skype, gaming

When I launch Skype at the same time as a game (Killing Floor), all my in-game sounds are muted.
I can still hear my friends on Skype, but I can't hear any in-game sounds.

I'm using Windows 8 and tried messing with the mixer,  but it didn't help.

Any advice is helpful.

Comment: I believe Skype by default mutes other sounds when you're on a call. There's probably something in the settings for that. I'd give a more in depth answer, but I recently stopped using Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Click the sound icon on the task bar and select Sounds. Then select communications tab, in here you can choose what to do with the volume. In your case, I would suspect you select Do Nothing.